# How does gillyweed actually work?

Tags: harry-potter, magic

In *The Goblet of Fire*, Harry consumes gillyweed (stolen from Snape by Dobby, I think) before entering the lake to save Ron. The book states that Harry felt a burning sensation and two gills opened up on either side of his neck.

This would ensure a continuous supply of oxygen to his brain (probably they are magically enhanced gills). But what about the other parts of his body?

If this happens, then Harry must technically be unable to get any oxygenated blood in his coronary artery and would get a heart attack and die soon after he enters the lake. Will the Oxygen in water even suffice, because, I don't think Gamp's law would allow generation of oxygen.

I'm saying this by assuming that Harry has normal "muggle" physiology, (given their appearance and food, I don't think I'm wrong here) and that Gillyweed does not change Harry in any way other than at the neck.

Then, how does Gillyweed work?

By the way, do wizards even have physiology? I don't think it is taught in Hogwarts.

Comment: I think you might be overthinking this one.

Comment: Reckon it's by magic...

Comment: Magic is great, but it can't do everything; Courtesy-Gamp's Law

Comment: @Krishna It can't do everything, but it can do this, because it happens in the books. I've answered on the assumption that you want an in-universe explanation, but as a warning (because you're close to the line), questions asking whether the real world science actually checks out aren't accepted here.

Comment: It increases the midichorine count

Answer (score 3):

## Magic

Gillyweed is a magical plant that produces a magical transformation so that the user is capable of surviving underwater (at least for a limited period of time). In addition to allowing them to survive, there are other aspects of the transformation so that they're more suited to an underwater environment.

> I'm saying this by assuming ... that Gillyweed does not change Harry in any way other than at the neck.

This is an incorrect assumption. The physical transformation due to eating gillyweed consists of more than just gills on the neck.

> ... He stretched out his hands in front of him and stared at them. They looked green and ghostly under the water, and they had become webbed. He twisted around and looked at his bare feet - they had become elongated and his toes were webbed, too; it looked as though he had sprouted flippers.
>
> The water didn't feel icy any more, either ... on the contrary, he felt pleasantly cool, and very light ... Harry struck out once more, marvelling at how far and fast his flipper-like feet propelled him through the water, and noticing how clearly he could see, and how he no longer needed to blink. ...
>   <sub>Harry Potter and the Goblet of Fire, Chapter Twenty-Six - The Second Task</sub>

In terms of effects that Harry could observe, we have:

- Gill
- Webbed hands/fingers
- Webbed toes, elongated feet
- Resilient to water temperature
- Bouyancy
- Changes to eyes (not needing to blink) and vision

There are likely other changes that Harry couldn't observe to allow him to actually be able to survive underwater.

Answer (score 2):

Average figure for oxygen content of water is 10mg/L. A good fish gill can extract 90%.

Resting oxygen demand is around 250ml/min but can increase 20-fold in strenuous exercise.

The gills would need a flow of around 30 - 600 L/min of water over them.

We do know magic can move items, so moving water over the gills quickly might be more in keeping with the rules of the Harry Potter universe than creating oxygen from nowhere.

First three paragraphs are fairly sound (although based on averages so some variation exists). Last one is entirely speculation I'm afraid.

Comment: That's great, (I cannot upvote yet). I'm not really going to ask, but just contemplating about his BP at the moment.